# passing value from controller to view undefined variable error

Tags: laravel

```
public function welcome()
{
    $posts = new Post;
    $data = $posts->data();

    return view('welcome', compact("data"));
}
```

Method in **Post** model:

```
public function data()
{ 
    return ['name ' => 'ABC', 'company'=> 'com']; 
}
```

This is Controller

```
{{ $data['name'] }}
{{ $data['company'] }}
```

This is view

I have passed value from controller to view and get undefined variable error

Comment: Please can you show the code for the `Post` class.

Comment: Public function data(){ return ['name ' => 'ABC', 'company'=> 'com']; }

Comment: I will mark accepted if any answer worked correctly

Comment: Please can you provide a screenshot of the error you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

First of all $posts = new Post will not return you a data rather return an instance of Post class, instead find a post like this one.

```
$posts = Post::find(1);
```

You can do it like this one

```
public function welcome()
{
     $posts = Post::find(1);
     $data['data'] = $posts->my_relationship;

     return view('welcome', $data);
}
```

and call it in view

```
{{$data->name}}
{{$data->company}}
```

assuming that my_relationship is a relation attached to your post model. Otherwise you can directly pass that post to a view. like this one

```
public function welcome()
{
     $posts = Post::find(1);
     $data['data'] = $posts;

     return view('welcome', $data);
}
```

assuming that name and company field is placed in your post table

Comment: It's not working I have also used this it's also not working  public function show(Post $post)
{       
$post = Post::find($post);
return view('posts.show',compact('post'));
}

Comment: can you show me the return of this, Post::find($post); ?

Comment: Public function data(){ return ['name ' => 'ABC', 'company'=> 'com']; }

Comment: is that a function ? or a data ? I mean, the data returned when you execute this Post::find($post); ?

Comment: Public function data(){ return ['name ' => 'ABC', 'company'=> 'com']; } this is function in model class public function welcome()
{
    $posts = new Post //object of Model;
    $data = $posts->data() //passing data function to data veriable;

    return view('welcome', compact("data")); //return view compact data veriable
}

Comment: please check my new answer. I think it will already solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function in your model to this.

```
public function scopeData() {
   return ['name ' => 'ABC', 'company'=> 'com'];
}
```

call this in your controller like this.

```
public function welcome()
{
     $post = Post::data();
     $data['data'] = $post;

     return view('welcome', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the index `name` inside your `data()` method (`'name '`). This won't produce an `undefined variable error`, however, it will produce an `Undefined index` error as your trying to access `'name'` and not `'name '` in your view.

To fix this you should simply be able to remove the space in your `data()` method:

```
public function data()
{ 
    return ['name' => 'ABC', 'company'=> 'com']; 
}
```

Comment: I have no spare gave in method and value i have tried

Comment: @Hammad Sorry but I'm not sure what you're trying to say.